# PyGTK - Retrieve / Save formatted text TextBuffer/Sqlite3

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am implementing text formatting between `gtk.TextBuffer`(across `gtk.TextView`) and `Sqlite3 table`. Text formatting in `TextView` is working normally, my problem is to save and retrieve the formatted text in a `Sqlite3 table` (TEXT type field).

Basically I format the text in a `TextBuffer` as follows:

```
class db(object):
   text_tag = 0

def format(self, constant): 
        if self.textbuffer.get_selection_bounds() != ():
            start, end = self.textbuffer.get_selection_bounds()
            self.textbuffer.apply_tag(constant, start, end)

def on_bold_btn_clicked(self, widget):
        db.text_tag = db.text_tag+1
        self.tt_bold = gtk.TextTag("bold_"+str(db.text_tag))
        self.tt_bold.set_property("weight", pango.WEIGHT_BOLD) 
        self.TextTagTable.add(self.tt_bold)

        self.format(self.tt_bold)
```

at saving time in table I retrieve the text formatted as follows:

```
textbuffer.get_text (textbuffer.get_start_iter (), textbuffer.get_end_iter (), include_hidden_chars = True)
```

As far as I understood the documentation [gtk.TextBuffer.get_text](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--get-text), texts with tags are deleted if include_hidden_chars is False, so when True, the text would be saved correctly formatted?

The formatted text display object's is a TextView, which at runtime, show correctly the formated text, but apparently, the text is not being saved / restored with the formatting done.

Does anyone know if I forgot something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize()

http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--serialize